# How do I determine if it's appropriate to cache a hashCode() result?

Tags: c#, java, performance, hash, theory

Given I have an immutable class of which a `GetHashCode()` function has been written, how do I know if it would be beneficial to cache the hash result, or in most cases is it even wise to do so?

Considering that the performance of a `GetHashCode()` calculation has been optimised for primitives and string values, is it even something I should bother considering?

A typical `GetHashCode()` of mine might look like the following:

```
//C#
public override int GetHashCode() {
    int hash = 13;
    hash = 13 * hash + IntValue;
    hash = 13 * hash + (StringValue1 == null ? 0 : StringValue1.GetHashCode());
    hash = 13 * hash + (StringValue2 == null ? 0 : StringValue2.GetHashCode());
    return hash;
}
```

My thoughts on the matter of situations where it might be wise are:

1. If it is intended to be the key of a map or dictionary.
2. If the said map will have many lookups within its lifetime.

Comment: When profiling shows that `GetHashCode` is taking up a significant amount of time.

Comment: Point 1) seems irrelevant. Point 2) should surface in a profiler.

Comment: You can simplify the first line with `int hash = IntValue;` String.hashCode() in Java is already cached so there might not be as much value as you might think in this case.

Comment: Thankyou guys for your comments, I possibly preemptively posed the question wanting peer thoughts on the subject.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your point "1" merely defines when you should implement `GetHashCode()` (and a matching `Equals`) - and in such scenarios you should ("2") expect it to be queried a *moderate* number of times. However, the key here is profiling, or a pre-existing knowledge of the scenario. For example, if your hash is actually taking a hash over a large-ish inner **array** then it is probably worth caching. In such cases, I would cache it lazily (perhaps as an `int?`) unless I know it is *going* to be used as a key (always), in which case I might pre-calculate it eagerly.

In most cases, though, just calculate it on-demand each time.

Comment: Thankyou Marc, I should have thought more about the question before asking. I have in some cases cached something which may have had an immutable array and done as you suggested, using an `int?`.